# Mask is not extending to scrollable portion

Tags: css, extjs, mask

I have  set

```
.x-mask {
   height:100% !important;
}
```

But the parent window is scrollable. So when I scroll the window, the bottom portion does not have mask. Any way to solve this issue?

I am using extjs.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS isn't written correctly:

```
.x-mask {
 height:100%;
}
```

If this doesn't fix your problem you would have to supply us with more code and/or a link to your website or a fiddle showing the issue.

Comment: Ya I put like this. I mistaked in my post.

Comment: I did not given anything in js for masking. Only set `modal: true`. And in css as given.

Answer (score 1):

```
x-mask {
 position:fixed;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
```